# Use Material Design for app made in Tasker App Factory?

Tags: android, wifi, material-design, tasker

I made a very simple app which simply puts my phone on vibrate whenever I'm near a specific WiFi SSID. I know there are several apps that do this but this one is pre-configured for a specific WiFi so the user doesn't need to input the SSID.

My app was originally made with Tasker's App Factory since my programming knowledge is very limited. I would like to update my app with Material Design if I could. I've seen some resources that Google has put out on Material Design but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on how to update this app. I'm assuming I would probably have to write this app again from scratch instead of using App Factory. I couldn't find any tutorials that show you how to manage your Audio Profiles using near by WiFi SSIDs. What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having trouble with this? If so, can you give an example of what would you like to achieve with managing audio profiles?

//edit

that wouldn't be too complicated:

1. create a profile, with two triggers: `[state] WiFi Near` and `[state]Variable Value`

   - WiFi Near - set here desired network name
   - Variable Value - name it for example `wifiVibrate` and set to trigger if value is `true`
2. add `Vibrate` action

now you need to create a second profile, with time trigger set to 00:00 (so every day at midnight). That profile should check the day of the week and if it matches one of the days saved in apps' settings, change `wifiVibrate` value to `true` (otherwise set it to `false`)

as for the storing and checking the weekdays, i'd create a scene with 7 checkboxes. Each checkbox state would correspond with an array item, so if it's state is changed - proper array item would be updated (monday selected -> `wifiDay1=true` etc).

To do this, each checkbox must have two actions assigned to `change`:

1. Variable Set wifiDay1 = true (if new_val=1)
2. Variable Set wifiDay1 = false (if new_val=0)

so you'd end up having `wifiDay` array with 7 items (true/false). All you need to do now is to check every day at midnight if array's item value for that day is `true`.

#### Material design

is really quite simple. To have a Material-style header just add a rectangular and fill it with proper color. Same for buttons, toggles, fonts etc.

In fact, there are some [nice tutorials on tasker scenes with material design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0imp5CbwfW4)

Comment: Basically the app would be pre-configured to put your phone on vibrate whenever it's near a specific WiFi SSID. The UI would be very simple and just let you select which days you'd like the app to activate on so to help with battery.